# getting fatal error while initializing repo

Tags: android, cyanogenmod, repo

I am reading this [wiki](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_tomato) for building a custom os for my yureka device.But,the following command

```
repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.1
```

is giving me fatal errors

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.
>   fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please tell me how to solve this fatal error.

Comment: please try if `git clone https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git`　work on your PC.

Comment: yes git clone is working with no error.But why repo init is giving error